# Is it a good idea to buy a garden property/allotment?

Tags: germany, investment-property

If I have the capital to buy a garden property (“Freizeitgrundstück/Schrebergarten“), would it be a good idea financial wise?

Are garden properties a stable form of investment? What things do I have to look out for? I don't really expect any gain, I just don't want to lose money (with 0% interest rates at the bank I would lose money due to inflation...).

I would look for a property near a big city, so I would suspect it to be easy to resell the property if I want to make a bigger investment like a house.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say it depend where you live. For example, where I live the value of properties (even garden property) tends to grow pretty well, so you would likely not loose money due to inflation. You could expect at least minimal gain. On the other hand, I don't live in Germany so I don't know much about properties value in the last years. If you can get a list of property prices for the last 5-10 years (in a major city) you could have an idea of the expected return if you decide to buy the property. Maybe some other people from Germany could give you a better answer since I live in North America.

**Edit : turned my comment into an actual answer.**